# How to add text after span conditionally, only if span text is not empty

Tags: html, css, webpack

I have this HTML:

```
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="a-section">A</span> •
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="b-section"><%= b.text %></span> •
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="c-section"><%= c.text %></span> •
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="d-section"><%= d.text %></span> •
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="e-section"><%= e.menu %></span>
```

In case if any of my params (webpack variables) is empty (`<%= b.text %>`, `<%= c.text %>`, etc) I've got this input

[image]

How would you check if <%= b.text %> is empty and skip adding the • so I in that case I would get `A • B • C` only.

Comment: The best way to fix this is to not put the dots in if the variable is empty. I don't know how you do that with webpack, but I've added the tag to bring experts in that technology to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is about html and css, then dots should be generated via CSS or included into a tag to be accessible via CSS.

example:

```css
span+span:before {
  content: ' • ';
 /* your own style from here , padding, margin, color, ... */
}

span:empty {
  display: none;
}
/* show me what's behind the empty span */
span:empty + span {color:green;}
```

```html
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="a-section">A</span>
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="b-section"><%= b.text %></span>
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="c-section"><%= c.text %></span>
<span class="footer-nav-item"><!-- looks like i'm empty --></span>
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="d-section"><%= d.text %></span>
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="e-section"><%= e.menu %></span>
```

If the last dot is to be shown too

```css
span:after {
  content: ' • ';
 /* your own style from here , padding, margin, color, ... */
}

span:empty {
  display: none;
}

/* show me what's behind the empty span */
span:empty + span {color:green;}
```

```html
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="a-section">A</span>
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="b-section"><%= b.text %></span>
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="c-section"><%= c.text %></span>
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="d-section"><%= d.text %></span>
<span class="footer-nav-item"><!-- looks like i'm empty --></span>
<span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="e-section"><%= e.menu %></span>
<span class="footer-nav-item"><!-- looks like i'm empty --></span>
```

Comment: That is looking good but when I am hovering the dot becomes a part of `a href` is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: @sreginogemoh your sample doesn't show any tag , how am i supposed to understand what you are telling me ? can you clarify , so i can help further. If your `<%= d.text %>`is meant to produce a link, then update my css  selector  generating the pseudo `span:before a` , then the :empty selector is useless if there is no link to genertae it. Please clarify, so i can make a clean answer or delete this one whichmight be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Make the dot a pseudo element and you can consider `:empty` selector:

```css
.footer-nav-item:not(:empty):not(:last-child):after {
  content:" • ";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="a-section">A</span>
  <span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="b-section">B</span>
  <span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="c-section"></span>
  <span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="d-section">D</span>
  <span class="footer-nav-item" data-target="e-section">E</span>
</div>
```

Comment: how would you amend the last one?

Comment: @sreginogemoh you mean you also want a dot after the last one?